# GWT: adding events to MenuItem possible?

Tags: gwt

I wanna implement MenuItems in a declarative way,but not able to add events to menuitems or sub-menu items in UIBinder. adding events to normal widgets is possible but how to add events to menuitems

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the clickevent to something else. Maybe you can create your own component. This component extends from FocusPanel. Within the MyFousPanel is the menuitem.

```
MyFocusPanel wrapper = new MyFocusPanel();
// wrapper.add(menuitem);
wrapper.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // Handle the click
    }
});
```

Of course you can use you own component in ui.xml file's.